# Group string column by rows containing same words in a new column

Tags: python, pandas, regex

on a pandas dataframe I have a column and the rows are strings with different phrases but they may have a same pattern ( a same word) and I would like to group that

The objective is find words of the string duplicated in other strings, and create a column showing just that words

```
[column 1 ]                               
three Apples                                
big panda                                    
a dog called jack                               
the panda is here                             
some applesize                                
big Dog                                     
three dogs here
```

Output

```
[column 1 ]                [newCol]               
three Apples                three, apples                 
big panda                   panda                   
a dog called jack           dog                     
the panda is here           panda                   
some applesize              apples                  
big Dog                     dog                     
three dogs here            three, dog, here
```

As there are thousand of entries, imagine we cant read and do manual with the words we want

Any idea is wellcome

Comment: if your dataframe is `df`, do `df2 = df.groupby(['newCol'])`

Comment: what is the logic ? For example, why is there **apple** instead of **three** in first row.

Comment: thank you that was my mistake, it must show both, three and apple, corrected